# Can't use "Times New Roman Bold" programmatically in Swift 5

Tags: ios13, swift5, xcode11

I'm trying to use UIFont(name: "Times New Roman Bold", size: 30.0) at run time but it's returning `nil`

Here is my code -

```
lblHeader.font = UIFont(name: "Times New Roman Bold", size: 30.0)
```

But `lblHeader` is returning `SFUI-Regular` when I printed in the console.

I've tried following combination but no luck -

`Times New Roman Bold`

`Times New Roman-Bold`

`Times New Roman-bold`

`Times New Roman bold`

`TimesNewRoman Bold`

`TimesNewRoman-Bold`

Comment: [iosfonts.com](http://iosfonts.com/) has it as "TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT", but I've no idea if that's the right identifier here or not.

Comment: @Rup yes it's working. I got all iOS font names here - https://gist.github.com/tadija/cb4ec0cbf0a89886d488d1d8b595d0e9

Comment: @Rup post your answer so that others can get help fro your answer.

Comment: Thanks, but your gist is better. Post that as an answer yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer here - [iOS Fonts](https://gist.github.com/tadija/cb4ec0cbf0a89886d488d1d8b595d0e9)

But thanks to [Rup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243245/rup) for the help.

I hope this answer will help others. 
Happy coding :)